# R: How to "fill" a grid with points

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following function:

```
# function: defined the first way

my_function_a <- function(x) {
  
  final_value = sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2]) + x[3] 
  
 
}

    #function : defined the second way
    
    my_function_b <- function(input_1, input_2, input_3) {
    
    final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3 
     
    }
```

**Goal:** I want to evaluate this function at different points so I can make a 3 Dimensional graph.

**First Attempt:**

I tried a very basic approach to evaluate this function at a series of fixed points (using a grid):

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

#create grid and evaluate function
input_1 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_2 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_3 <- seq(0,100,1)


my_grid <- data.frame(input_1, input_2, input_3)
my_grid$final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3
```

And then I tried to plot this function:

```
#plot function

plot_ly() %>% 
        add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$input_1, y=my_grid$input_2, z=my_grid$input_3, type='mesh3d') %>%
        add_surface(
                z = my_grid %>% as.matrix(),
                surfacecolor = my_grid,
                cauto=F,
                cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
                cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
        )
```

The plot of this function looks deceptively "simple":
[image]

Then I realized that this is because I have only evaluated this function at "evenly spaced" points, for example:

```
 head(my_grid)
  input_1 input_2 input_3 final_value
1       0       0       0    1.000000
2       1       1       1    2.381773
3       2       2       2    2.493151
4       3       3       3    2.151128
5       4       4       4    2.589554
6       5       5       5    4.324738
```

For instance, in the above data frame, you will not find a combination of points such as `(input_1 = 5, input_2 = 2, input_3 =11)`

**Second Attempt**

Next, I tried to add some "randomness" to decide which points to evaluate the function at:

```
#create grid and evaluate function
input_1 <- rnorm(100,100,20)
input_2 <- rnorm(100,100,20)
input_3 <- rnorm(100,100,20)


my_grid <- data.frame(input_1, input_2, input_3)
my_grid$final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3 


#create plot
plot_ly() %>% 
        add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$input_1, y=my_grid$input_2, z=my_grid$input_3, type='mesh3d') %>%
        add_surface(
                z = my_grid %>% as.matrix(),
                surfacecolor = my_grid,
                cauto=F,
                cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
                cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
        )
```

[image]

The plot now appears to contain a higher level of complexity, as seen in the data used to create the plot:

```
head(my_grid)
    input_1   input_2   input_3 final_value
1  82.09936  65.48251 103.26060   102.78460
2  81.94343 118.69431  76.51834    77.55103
3  76.90372 115.58958 123.96159   124.16298
4 128.52814  85.52632  69.02835    68.53927
5  96.89466 121.53117 124.39381   124.32069
6  97.59012 126.80997  87.54789    87.76038
```

**Question:** Are there any "better" ways to fill this grid with points so that you can a "better looking and more realistic" plot? For instance, is it possible to create a grid such that

```
#iterate input_1 from 1-100 AND fix input_2 and input_3 as constant
input_1 = 1, input_2 = 1, input_3 = 1 ; input_1 = 2, input_2 = 1, input_3 = 1 ; etc; input_1 = 100, input_2 = 1, input_3 = 1

#iterate input_2 from 1-100 AND fix input_1 and input_3 as constant 
input_1 = 1, input_2 = 2, input_3 = 1; input_1 = 1, input_2 = 3, input_3 = 1 , etc
```

Is it possible to evaluate "my_function_a" or "my_function_b" using this kind of grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem is caused by `my_grid` being incompletely filled.

```
head(my_grid)
```

> ```
>   input_1 input_2 input_3 final_value
> 1       0       0       0    1.000000
> 2       1       1       1    2.381773
> 3       2       2       2    2.493151
> 4       3       3       3    2.151128
> 5       4       4       4    2.589554
> 6       5       5       5    4.324738
> ```

All three input variables are advanced simultaneously which creates a line in three-dimensional space.

Perhaps, you meant to use `expand.grid()` to create a three-dimensional grid:

```
n <- 3
my_grid <- expand.grid(i1 = 1:n, i2 = 1:n, i3 = 1:n)
my_grid$final_value = with(my_grid, sin(i1) + cos(i2) + i3)
head(my_grid)
```

> ```
>   i1 i2 i3 final_value
> 1  1  1  1   2.3817733
> 2  2  1  1   2.4495997
> 3  3  1  1   1.6814223
> 4  1  2  1   1.4253241
> 5  2  2  1   1.4931506
> 6  3  2  1   0.7249732
> ```

Now, the plot

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$i1, y=my_grid$i2, z=my_grid$i3, type='mesh3d') %>%
  add_surface(
    z = my_grid %>% as.matrix(),
    surfacecolor = my_grid,
    cauto=F,
    cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
    cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
  )
```

becomes

[image]

Comment: I made a slight change to the graphing code: plot_ly() %>% 
    add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$i1, y=my_grid$i2, z=my_grid$final_value, type='mesh3d') %>%
    add_surface(
        z = my_grid %>% as.matrix(),
        surfacecolor = my_grid,
        cauto=F,
        cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
        cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
    )

Comment: I also found a way to change the increments of the gird: n <- 3
 my_grid <- expand.grid(i1 = seq(from=1, to=n, by=0.1), i2 = 1:n, i3 = 1:n)

Comment: @noob Glad you found a solution on your own! `seq(from, to, by)` would have been my suggestion as well.